# Error in rendering and ActionBar Overlay layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have opened a project in android studio and i tried to preview the design and here is the problem, the rendering has some error and it shows  actionBar overlay layout how can i fix this problem

here is my build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "development.assistant.project.s_assistant"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    google()
}
```

this is a screenshot

[image: error in rendering]

here is gpa calculator xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.assistant.learn.assistant12.Calculator.Cgpa">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="   ENTER YOUR SGPA  "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="S5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/c3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="S6"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/c4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c7"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="S8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/c6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/c6" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="S7"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/c5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="S3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/c1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="S1S2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="S4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/c2">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FIND"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the rest of activity files just the same problem

Comment: share error logcat...

Comment: post xml layolut files, gradle cannot help solve this issue

Comment: Checkout these:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271824/action-bar-shown-in-display-of-android-studio-but-not-in-my-actual-app , http://android.xsoftlab.net/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Comment: I have posted one of activity files, can you help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same error. In my styles.xml I changed

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I learned it here:

[Android Studio layout design view shows overlay after upgrade to v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330684/android-studio-layout-design-view-shows-overlay-after-upgrade-to-v3-0)

Comment: In case the Theme in the UI layout editor is different, change it back to Apptheme will help..